# Strange notation in properties of characteristic functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

In https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_of_a_set, various properties of characteristic functions are discussed.

However, the notation used there is confusing. In particular how is $\chi_E (1 - \chi_F )$ to be read? If $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E \subseteq X$ and $(1 - \chi_F )$ outputs a number, then $\chi_E$ might not be able to apply to the output of $(1 - \chi_F )$, unless $E$ is assumed to contain $1$ and $0$.

Likewise, what is the implicit ordering relative to which $sup_{\alpha}$ and  $inf_{\alpha}$ are to be understood? (i.e, they are the supremum and infimum with respect to what partial ordering?).

Comment: 1) should read $\chi_{E\setminus F}(x)=\chi_E(x)(1-\chi_F(x))$. This is a [pointwise product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_product). The other equations are analogous. You need to add such arguments to 3), 4) to understand those equations, as working with the supremum or infimum of a subset of $\{0,\,1\}$.

Comment: It seems to me that the pointwise product here can either be understood as multiplication on the natural numbers (if 1 and 0 are not coded as sets), or as set intersection (if 1 is defined as $\emptyset$ and 0 as $\emptyset$). Is that right? Ah, so supremum of $\{0,1 \}$ means the least upper bound with respect to the less than or equal $\leq$ relation on $\mathbb{N}$, so that $sup \{0,1 \} = 1$?

Comment: The values $0,\,1$ of CFs should be coded as integers, so they multiply etc. as per primary school arithmetic. You're right about the supremum of $\{0,\,1\}$, but we're also interested in the suprema of its subsets. For example, 3) means $\chi_E(x)$ is $1$ if $x\in E_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, or $0$ or otherwise.